# Highcharts: how to add padding/spacing from top of chart

Tags: highcharts

How I can add padding/spacing from top of chart?

```
minPadding: 0.05,  - is not working
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drqjamLo/

Comment: maxPadding? http://jsfiddle.net/drqjamLo/1/

Answer (score 10):

Add spacingTop

```
chart: {
    spacingTop: 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chart: {
    spacing: [20, 0, 0, 0] // top right bottom left
}
```